# Where does echo output go to, when running a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

The following will output to stdout if the script is run in a terminal:

```
 echo "some message"
```

If the script is called by another script, where does the output go to? Is there any significant overhead involved?

I'm using GNU bash, version 4.3.33.

Many thanks

Comment: It goes to stdout still

Comment: When a process (in this case, interactive bash running in the terminal) spawns a subprocess (shell script in this case), the subprocess inherits the FDs from parent process. So, it will be same as your interactive shell's stdout; unless you have redirected the stdout to some file or pipe.

Answer (score 1):

The output of

```
echo "some message"
```

should go to the `stdout` except (not exclusive) in cases where

1. You have a o/p redirection, as given below, which affect the `echo` statement.

   ```
   exec 1>/dev/null # 1 is the file descriptor for stdout, this should be before the echo

   ./script >outfile # The whole output is redirected to a file
   ```
2. You have a `do-nothing` directive(`:`) before the echo command

   ```
   : echo "some message" # Does nothing
   ```

Comment: Many thanks, especially the file descriptor for stdout; I assume this is useful for redirecting ALL echo-commands in a script, using a single statement.